# Design a chess game using object-oriented principles

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, game, chess

I would like to know if my approach is correct and how could it could be improved? Also, is there a way to get rid of the relation between the `Piece` and the `Board`? At the moment, I am storing the position of the piece both in the piece and on the board. Is there some way to change that?

I have considered a `Game` to contain an instance of the `Board` and the two `Players` (one black, one white). The pieces contain a connection to the Board, because in order to determine if they are valid, we need to know the relationship to other pieces.

Could I use design patterns for this? Should I use interfaces instead of the super class?

#### Game.java

```
public class Game {
    private Board board = new Board();
    private Player white;
    private Player black;
    public Game() {
        super();
    }

    public void setColorWhite(Player player) {
        this.white = player;
    }

    public void setColorBlack(Player player) {
        this.black = player;
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(Board board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public Player getWhite() {
        return white;
    }

    public void setWhite(Player white) {
        this.white = white;
    }

    public Player getBlack() {
        return black;
    }

    public void setBlack(Player black) {
        this.black = black;
    }

    public boolean initializeBoardGivenPlayers() {
        if(this.black == null || this.white == null)
            return false;
        this.board = new Board();
        for(int i=0; i<black.getPieces().size(); i++){
            board.getSpot(black.getPieces().get(i).getX(), black.getPieces().get(i).getY()).occupySpot(black.getPieces().get(i));
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

#### Player.java

```
public class Player {
    public final int PAWNS = 8;
    public final int BISHOPS = 2;
    public final int ROOKS = 2;
    public boolean white;

    private List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<>();

    public Player(boolean white) {
        super();
        this.white = white;
    }

    public List<Piece> getPieces() {
        return pieces;
    }


    public void initializePieces(){
        if(this.white == true){
            for(int i=0; i<PAWNS; i++){ // draw pawns
                pieces.add(new Pawn(true,i,2));
            }
            pieces.add(new Rook(true, 0, 0));
            pieces.add(new Rook(true, 7, 0));
            pieces.add(new Bishop(true, 2, 0));
            pieces.add(new Bishop(true, 5, 0));
            pieces.add(new Knight(true, 1, 0));
            pieces.add(new Knight(true, 6, 0));
            pieces.add(new Queen(true, 3, 0));
            pieces.add(new King(true, 4, 0));
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0; i<PAWNS; i++){ // draw pawns
                pieces.add(new Pawn(true,i,6));
            }
            pieces.add(new Rook(true, 0, 7));
            pieces.add(new Rook(true, 7, 7));
            pieces.add(new Bishop(true, 2, 7));
            pieces.add(new Bishop(true, 5, 7));
            pieces.add(new Knight(true, 1, 7));
            pieces.add(new Knight(true, 6, 7));
            pieces.add(new Queen(true, 3, 7));
            pieces.add(new King(true, 4, 7));
        }

    }
}
```

#### Board.java

```
public class Board {
    private Spot[][] spots = new Spot[8][8];

    public Board() {
        super();
        for(int i=0; i<spots.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<spots.length; j++){
                this.spots[i][j] = new Spot(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    public Spot getSpot(int x, int y) {
        return spots[x][y];
    }

}
```

#### Spot.java

```
public class Spot {
    int x;
    int y;
    Piece piece;

    public Spot(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        piece = null;
    }

    public void occupySpot(Piece piece){
        //if piece already here, delete it, i. e. set it dead
        if(this.piece != null)
            this.piece.setAvailable(false);
        //place piece here
        this.piece = piece;
    }

    public boolean isOccupied() {
        if(piece != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public Piece releaseSpot() {
        Piece releasedPiece = this.piece;
        this.piece = null;
        return releasedPiece;
    }

}
```

#### Piece.java

```
public class Piece {
    private boolean available;
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Piece(boolean available, int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.available = available;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return available;
    }
    public void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        this.available = available;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isValid(Board board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY){
        if(toX == fromX && toY == fromY)
            return false; //cannot move nothing
        if(toX < 0 || toX > 7 || fromX < 0 || fromX > 7 || toY < 0 || toY > 7 || fromY <0 || fromY > 7)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

#### King.java

```
public class King extends Piece{

    public King(boolean available, int x, int y) {
        super(available, x, y);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Board board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if(super.isValid(board, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;
        if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs((toX - fromX)),2)) + Math.pow(Math.abs((toY - fromY)), 2) != Math.sqrt(2)){
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

#### Knight.java

```
public class Knight extends Piece{

    public Knight(boolean available, int x, int y) {
        super(available, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Board board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if(super.isValid(board, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;

        if(toX != fromX - 1 && toX != fromX + 1 && toX != fromX + 2 && toX != fromX - 2)
            return false;
        if(toY != fromY - 2 && toY != fromY + 2 && toY != fromY - 1 && toY != fromY + 1)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

#### Bishop.java

```
public class Bishop extends Piece{

    public Bishop(boolean available, int x, int y) {
        super(available, x, y);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Board board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if(super.isValid(board, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;

        if(toX - fromX == toY - fromY)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

#### Rook.java

```
public class Rook extends Piece{

    public Rook(boolean available, int x, int y) {
        super(available, x, y);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Board board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if(super.isValid(board, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;
        if(toX == fromX)
            return true;
        if(toY == fromY)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Queen.java

```
public class Queen extends Piece{

    public Queen(boolean available, int x, int y) {
        super(available, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Board board, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if(super.isValid(board, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) == false)
            return false;
        //diagonal
        if(toX - fromX == toY - fromY)
            return true;
        if(toX == fromX)
            return true;
        if(toY == fromY)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is Pawn.java file ? I did not found that.

Comment: @Nitin Kumar i have forgotten indeed to write it down apparently, but i no longer have the project due to some hardware issues...

Comment: bishop moves only in diagonal shape if it is in white place means its only moves in white diagonally otherwise moves in black

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Without offering a deep code review (as I don't have a lot of specific Java knowledge), let's look at what a full "move" entails in chess:

- Player chooses piece to move.
- Piece makes legal move according to its own move rules.
- In addition to purely move-based rules, there's also capture logic, so a bishop cannot move from a1-h8 if there's a piece sitting on c3.
- If the player was previous under check and the move does not remove the check, it must be undone.
- If the move exposes check, it must be undone / disallowed.
- If player captures a piece, remove the piece (including en passant!)
- If the piece is a pawn reaching the back rank, promote it.
- If the move is a castling, set the new position of the rook accordingly. But a king and rook can only castle if they haven't moved, so you need to keep track of that. And if the king moves through a check to castle, that's disallowed, too.
- If the move results in a stalemate or checkmate, the game is over.

There may be more even (?). This is a complicated step, more than just counting and subsequently occupying spaces.

So my general intuition would be to just call:

```
Game.move(currentSpot, NewSpot);
```

And the move method would contain all the code to validate the steps above:

- Check `Piece.isValidMove(currentSpot, newSpot);` - probably need castling logic here since king moves more than 1 space and rook jumps the king)
- Check `Player.isChecked()` (which is just sugar for `Player.Pieces["King"].CanBeCaptured()` - more fun logic here!)
- Check if `newSpot` contains a piece and if so, `newSpot.Piece.Remove()`;
- Build some logic to call `Piece.CheckEnPassant()` (Piece is pawn, first move, 2 steps, past an enemy pawn who moved into capturing position on previous move - have fun with that!)
- `Piece.CheckPromote()` (Piece is pawn, move ends on opposing player's back rank)
- Check if `Game.isOver()`, which checks `Game.isStaleMate()` and `Game.isCheckMate()`.

Your Board class is highly anemic, you're only using it in your code as a proxy object for the array of spots. You might as well just create Board as an array of Spots in Game. In either case, you can already remove it from all your piece logic since all your logic is entirely predicated on the Xs and Ys you're passing in.

**UPDATE**

I would remove all your position properties from the piece. You're only using it as a proxy to figure out what spot the piece occupies during initializiation. Instead, remove `Player.initializePieces()` and just initialize the Board with the pieces in the right spot (Board.Spot.Piece = King, etc.) and then let players choose a color.

Comment: Further move: Taking a pawn en passent: If a pawn moves two positions in its first move, it can be taken by an opposing pawn in the very next move as if it had moved one position only. Offering a draw or giving up: The player whose move it is can offer a draw, and the other player can accept or reject it. And the player whose move it is can give up the game. After 50 moves with no piece taken or pawn moved the player can demand a draw. Same if the identical position is entered for the third time.

Comment: @Kyle Hale I believe to validate `isValidMove` should not be responsibility of piece but it should be the responsibility of validator. Is n't it ?

Comment: @MSach Yeah, you're probably right, I would move that to the Game class and just add the Source and Destination squares as parameters.

Comment: This is actually a superb non-trivial learning example for OO design and for illustrating tradeoffs, encapsulation, delegation. It also depends what your objective is, i.e. if both players are human, you only need simple methods to validate their moves and simplicity should trump efficiency, but if either is an AI, you need methods to efficiently generate and validate candidate moves (or indeed a depth-n tree), score them and prune them.

Answer (score 37):

My comments are with respect to design of the game.
I see responsibilities of entities are mixed up in many places

- Player should not initialize pieces. We can move the responsibility to board. Board and pieces doesn't need to know about players.
- Pieces should not handle move. Pieces can provide list of possible moves to reach the destination path but board should choose a valid path.
- Board should have check for "Check Mate" condition.
- Game should track the players move history and piece color selection.
- Player class should have only player details.

A rough class diagram is attached below
[image]

Answer (score 22):

**Some quick shots**

- a `if` condition written like `if (booleanVariable==true)` can be simplified to `if (booleanVariable)`
- you shouldn't have public variables like `public boolean white;`
- no constructor of `Game`, `Board`, `Player` and `Piece` should call `super()` because they are obviously not inheriting / extending any class.

**Some design quickshots**

- a chessgame needs a Board, 2 Players and 32 pieces.
- the pieces are part of the Board
- the Player moves the piece by rules
- the rules are bound to the type of piece and the pieces position on the board
- these rules needs to be evaluated by some object, either the `Game` or a `RuleEvaluator`.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using a boolean to flag if something is something (and thus implying that it isn't the other thing), consider an `enum`; in this case that doesn't buy you anything in terms of flexibility (since it's not as if there will ever be, say, red or purple or whatnot) but it will make your code much more clear.

On the game, instead of setting black and white separately, you should have a single `setPlayers(Player black, Player white)`, or better yet, have the board be a factory that provides the black and white `Player`s itself - if there's even a reason to have a Player object in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Couple of additions to everyone else:

- both `Player` and `Board` need to know where pieces are, both theirs and the opponents. Can't think offhand the best way to decompose this, but consider how they'll talk to each other with minimal duplication. I guess it makes more sense to put it under `Board`, then have `Player` store a reference to `Board` and either inherit or composite its methods:
- `*.isValid()` only check from- and to-coords, they currently don't check if there are intervening friendly or enemy pieces, or indeed if the to-spot is occupied. I think you should do that in one function at the Board level, it will get very ugly if you do that for each piece. You might need a helper function (iterator?) for each piece to generate `interveningSpots(fromX,fromY,toX,toY,pieceType)` so `Board.validMove()` can test if they're occupied.
- the name `Piece.isValid()` is confusing, it could mean either `validMove()` or `validPosition()`. Personally I'd rename it `validMove()`. (We'll also need a `validPosition()` if you ever implement promotion, but again, that would be implemented at Board level not Piece or Player)
- `King.isValid()` seems to currently always return false - bug?
- `Queen/Bishop/Rook.isValid()` currently allow null zero moves `(toX==fromX && toY==fromY)`. This might sound like nitpicking, but a) it might wrongly allow you to evade mate by "doing nothing" b) it is likely to mess up recursion in any AI you or someone might want to add.
- a tip for more performant and more compact code for `King.isValid()`: you don't need to take the sqrt; just directly test that dist2 = (dx^2 + dy^2) is either 1 or 2. And you don't need abs(dx) since the square of a negative number is positive. So:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(...) {
      if(!super.isValid(...)) {
          return false;

      int dist2 = Math.pow((toX - fromX), 2) + Math.pow((toY - fromY), 2);
      return (dist2 == 1 || dist2 == 2);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few different ways you can simplify your logic:

- As already mentioned, instead of writing `if (condition == true)`, write `if (condition)`.
- Likewise, instead of `if (condition == false)`, write `if (!condition)`.
- If you find yourself tempted to write:

  ```
  if (condition)
      return true;
  return false;
  ```

  ...instead write `return condition;`.
- Likewise, instead of:

  ```
  if (condition)
      return false;
  return true;
  ```

  ...write `return (!condition);`.
- If you're tempted to write:

  ```
  if (condition1)
      return true;
  if (condition2)
      return true;
  return false;
  ```

  ...consider instead `return condition1 || condition2;`.

In general, simplify logic if it increases clarify.